# What's the word for when a word means what it seems like it should mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm not talking about onomatopoeia—I don't mean a word that describes a sound—I mean something along the lines of an aptronym, i.e. a perfect name such as Anthony Camera for a photographer (true story). What is the word for when a word just sounds like exactly what it means? I heard the word for this once, long ago, and have since forgotten it.

"Push" and "Pull" might be examples, in that the sounds they form evoke the physical actions denoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of an [ideophone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideophone), a broader idea than just onomatopoeia (not restricted to sound).

[Mark Dingemanse explains ideophones](http://ideophone.org/three-misconceptions-about-ideophones/):

> English, for example, has ideophonic words like glimmer, twiddle, tinkle which are depictive of sensory imagery: their form betrays something of their meaning in ways that words "chair" and "dog" do not.

Comment: Just as a point of interest, Japanese is curious in that it conflates onomatopoeic and ideophonic nouns, e.g., "niko-niko" for gleaming teeth, "koro-koro" for rolling logs, and "kyoro-kyoro" for wandering around aimlessly.

Comment: @TheRaven: how is that conflating them?

Comment: @TheRaven: Not to mention "pera-pera" to describe fluent, rapid speech.

Comment: I believe the conflation, @Mechanicalsnail, is that while these words are not onomatopoeic, they are used as sound effects. Although, I would argue that koron-koron actually sounds like a bouncing/rolling object. We get the curious case of Chocolate Collon as a result of this association (imagine a little log-shaped cookie rolling down a hill koron-koron-koron…): http://www.amazon.com/Glico-Collon-Biscuit-Chocolate-Flavoured/dp/B00LKK65SU/

Answer (score 0):

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism) may be helpful.

Of the various terms mentioned in the article, **phenomime** might be close to what you are looking for.